# Pattern matching in Python?

Tags: string, python-2.7, search

I have a list of string representations of binary numbers. X characters are wildcards that can be 0 or 1.

I have a string `'10101011'` to search for in the below list.

```
line = '10101011'

my_list = ['1000101X','1000101X','11XXXXXX','111010XX','101XXXXX','100100XX','1000001X','1010110X']
```

The search string `line` has to match with `'101XXXXX'`, which is in the list.

I tried:

```
if any(line in s for s in my_list)
```

But figured out it is not possible to use this.

Is there any way? How can I do it?

Comment: Is your list actually a list of strings?

Comment: Yes.It is actually a list of strings got from the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the index of the X character and compare the strings up until that point.

```
def match(line, s):
    i = s.index('X')
    if s == line or (i and s[:i] == line[:i] and len(s) == len(line)) :
        return True
    return False

line = '10101011'
my_list = ['1000101X','1000101X','11XXXXXX','111010XX','101XXXXX','100100XX','1000001X','1010110X']

if any(match(line,s) for s in my_list):
    do something
```

If the X's are not all at the end of the string, find all the permutations, then filter them by non-wildcard digits:

```
import itertools

def expand_list(l):
    new_list = []
    for s in l:
        perms = ["".join(seq) for seq in itertools.product("01", repeat=len(s))]
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] != 'X':
                perms = [p for p in perms if p[i] == s[i]]
        new_list.extend(perms)
    return new_list

line = '10101011'
my_list = ['1000101X','1000101X','11XXXXXX','111010XX','101XXXXX','100100XX','1000001X','1010110X']

if line in expand_list(my_list):
    do something
```